# How do you remove NA's in geom_bar when plotting data subsets?

Tags: r, ggplot2, na

this is related to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403104/remove-unused-factor-levels-from-a-ggplot-bar-plot?lq=1), but the proposed solutions don't work in my case.

I've already posted a question regarding my large `data.frame` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22855197/how-do-you-get-geom-map-to-show-all-parts-of-a-map/22875922?noredirect=1#comment34951335_22875922), but if you just want to download it (>2000 rows) please do so via [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/87tnryu9zzf541t/ARCTP53_SOExample.txt?n=9895686).

So the **following code** is used to create a simple `geom_bar`barplot in `ggplot2`

```
gghist<-ggplot(ARCTP53_SOExample[ARCTP53_SoExample$Structural_motif=="NDBL/beta-sheets",],
aes(x=p53_IHC))
gghist+geom_bar()
```

This produces **this plot**:
[image: A barplot with lots of "NA's"]

As you can see, the NA's are plotted as well. I've tried various options to remove the NA's including the ***following***:

```
gghist<-ggplot(ARCTP53_SOExample[ARCTP53_SOExample$Structural_motif=="NDBL/beta-sheets",], aes(x=p53_IHC), drop=TRUE)
gghist+geom_bar()
gghist<-ggplot(ARCTP53_SOExample[ARCTP53_SOExample$Structural_motif=="NDBL/beta-sheets",], aes(x=p53_IHC), na.rm=TRUE)
gghist+geom_bar()
gghist<-ggplot(ARCTP53_SOExample[ARCTP53_SOExample$Structural_motif=="NDBL/beta-sheets",], aes(x=p53_IHC, na.rm=TRUE))
gghist+geom_bar()
gghist<-ggplot(ARCTP53_SOExample[ARCTP53_SOExample$Structural_motif=="NDBL/beta-sheets",], aes(x=factor(p53_IHC), na.rm=TRUE))
gghist+geom_bar()
 gghist<-ggplot(ARCTP53_SOExample[ARCTP53_SOExample$Structural_motif=="NDBL/beta-sheets",], aes(x=factor(p53_IHC))
    gghist+geom_bar(na.rm=TRUE)
```

And then I tried **this**:

```
gghist_2<-ggplot(na.omit(ARCTP53_SOExample[ARCTP53_EsoMutClean$Structural_motif=="NDBL/beta-sheets",]), aes(x=p53_IHC))
gghist_2+geom_bar()
```

Which gives me ***this error***:

```
Error in as.environment(where) : 'where' is missing
```

Further, I tried ***this***, which gives me the following **errors**

```
datasub<-ARCTP53_SOExample[!is.na(ARCTP53_SOExample)]
gghist_3<-ggplot(datasub[datasub$Structural_motif=="NDBL/beta-sheets",])
Error in datasub$Structural_motif : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

And this code doesn't work either:

```
gghist_3<-ggplot(datasub, aes(x=p53_IHC))
Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class character
```

So, does anyone know an easy solution to this? The `data.frame` is big and inherently has a lot of missing data depending on which column I'm looking at, but not all missing data is missing across all rows, so deleting any row that has a single "NA" in it, would be defeating the point.

Help is much appreciated.

Kind regards,

Oliver

**EDIT** Following Daniel's comments below, this what I get following the code *below*. As you can see the problem is still not solved. Sorry.

```
gghist<-ggplot(ARCTP53_SOExample[ARCTP53_SOExample$Structural_motif=="NDBL/beta-sheets" & is.na(ARCTP53_SOExample$p53_IHC) == F,], aes(x=p53_IHC))
gghist+geom_bar()
```

UPDATE: Re-Ran the code and for some reason it works now. Got the plot below:

[image: It works]

[image: NAs reduced but still there]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't downlaod your data, but this should work:

```
gghist<-ggplot(ARCTP53_SOExample[ARCTP53_SoExample$Structural_motif=="NDBL/beta-sheets" & is.na(ARCTP53_SOExample$p53_IHC) == F,], aes(x=p53_IHC))
gghist+geom_bar()
```

Comment: Just re-ran the code and it works now. Must've had a typo in it before. Thanks a mill @Daniel Falbel