# How to build world map in R and color selected countries

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-map

I'm trying to build a map showing a gradient of scores attributed to a selection of countries, these scores are stored in a dataframe (scores) alongside the corresponding country name:

```
Country Score
United States  0.4
France 0.2
India 0.6 etc.
```

I've tried the following (based on [How do you get geom_map to show all parts of a map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22855197/how-do-you-get-geom-map-to-show-all-parts-of-a-map)) but get an error (Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'region' not found)

```
world_map <- map_data('world')

gg <- ggplot(scores) +
 geom_map(dat = world_map, map = world_map, aes(map_id = region),
          fill = 'white', color = 'black' +
 geom_map(map = world_map, aes(map_id = region, fill = Score)
```

Grateful for any help as I can't seem to get anywhere with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22855197/how-do-you-get-geom-map-to-show-all-parts-of-a-map), you should be calling upon `Country` and `Score` in your second `geom_map` call. Also there are a few parentheses missing from your code and please note that `world_map` uses "USA", not "United States".

```
library(maps)
library(tidyverse)
scores <- read_table("
Country Score
USA  0.4
France 0.2
India 0.6")

world_map <- map_data("world")
gg <- ggplot(scores) + 
  geom_map(dat=world_map, map=world_map, 
                    aes(map_id=region), fill="white", color="black") + 
  geom_map(map=world_map, 
                    aes(map_id=Country, fill=Score), color="black") + 
  expand_limits(x = world_map$long, y = world_map$lat)
gg
```

[image]